# Can't load main class

Tags: java

It's a simple class and I am a beginner with Java.

[image]

I don't know why this code is not running and why it gives an error :
`Could not find or load main class`

```
class tuto{
      public static void main(String[] args){
             System.out.println("Hello World");
      }
}
```

Comment: change Syteme in System

Comment: I fixed the typo in the posted code because it is not in the screenshot, and the error message is related to the class name conflicting with the file name.  It's not a code syntax error.

Comment: Can you describe how you are trying to run this code? Also what massage you get when you hover your cursor over red `x` near line 1?

Comment: check if the file is in a package

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things which jump out at me when I look at your question.

The first thing is that you have unresolved compiler errors. If you see that red 'x' on the Problems tab, you should fix all the errors there before trying to run anything.

The second thing is that your class name doesn't match the file name in which it is defined.  For public classes the name of the class and the name of the file must match, and while your class isn't public, this is a widely followed Java convention and you will confuse people if you don't follow it.

As to your actual question, my best guess is that you have placed your class into a package and not declared it as such in your source code. If you go look at the Problems tab, it will tell you what is wrong and (often) how to fix it.

I can approximate your error message if I do the following:

[image: screen shot of runtime error]

In this case, I have an error over in the Problems tab complaining about the declared package.
Check to see if you have something similar:

[image: screen shot of compile error]

If you do, you can right-click the error message and select "Quick Fix", and eclipse will pop up a dialog offering to add the package declaration for you:

[image: screenshot of Quick Fix dialog]

Comment: But here he is not having a public class.Therefor it is not a must.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne good catch, I didn't notice that.  I've udpated my answer,

Comment: i changed it to the same class but it doesn't work it told :Unresolved compilation problem

Comment: @H-BooTz.exe Go to the problems tab, see what it says there, and update your question to show that error message.  Your compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong, but until you show us the error message, we're only guessing.

Answer (score 3):

In your code there is a compile error, that is because Syteme change it to `System`

```
Syteme.out.println("Hello World");
```

should be

```
 System.out.println("Hello World");
```

P.S
And in Java when you have a public class in a file, then file name must be that class name. It is a must. Otherwise you will get an error.

If you have this class in a package then you must specify the package declaration first

e.g

```
package abc;
```

Comment: If you look at the screen shot, it is `System` not `Systme`, the OP just typoed the code when posting it.

Comment: Do you have this class in a package? if so you must have the package declaration

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne You Are Right , i didn't add it to the package

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` not `Syteme.out.println`.

In Java (as somebody has already pointed) the name of the file should be of the `same name` of the `main class` within the same file.

Moreover, you should also declare an array using this syntax `array_type [] array_id` and not `array_type array_id []`.

Comment: My Mistake Just at when i wrote it at page look at the picture

Answer (score -1):

There might be a couple of problems:

1. If the class is in a package, make sure you specify it. eg: `package com.pak;`
2. The class with main method always needs to be public. `public class apples{}`

Comment: This rule applies only to public classes. Class from question is not public.

Comment: But if we don't specify it is a `public` or `private` class, shouldn't it be public by default?

Comment: No, there are four visibility modifiers: `public`, `protected`,  *default* (know also as *package-visibility* - when you don't specify any visibility modifier), and `private`. Classes (outer ones like one from OP screenshot, not inner/nested ones) can have only `public` or *default* modifiers.

Comment: No problem. Since we agree that this answer doesn't solve OP problem consider deleting it. Otherwise you risk getting downvotes.